# Sankey graphs blank when saved as SVG using plotly for python

Tags: python-3.x, plotly, plotly-python

as the title says whenever I’m saving a Sankey graph no matter if it’s large or small it always produces a blank svg. Is there a way to solve this issue? The graph display normally in my jupyter notebook but saves a blank svg (only title is visible).

I’m using plotly 3.6.1

I asked the same question already on the plotly community board, however, there was no response.

```
def drawSankeyForAreaFlow(area_flow_data, log_index):
sankeyData = getSankeyData(area_flow_data)

data = dict(
    type='sankey',
    node = dict(
      pad = 30,
      line = dict(
        width = 0.5
      ),
      label = ['label 1', 'label 2', 'label 3', 'label 4', 'label 5', 'label 6', 'label 7', 'label 8', 'label 9', 'label 10', 'label 11', 'label 12', 'label 13', 'label 14', 'label 15', 'label 16'],
      color = ['#FF40C5', '#FF4A80', '#FF713D', '#FF9600', '#E5B200', '#A4C700', '#47D400', '#00DB65', '#00DFAE', '#00E1F5', '#00DEFF', '#00D6FF', '#00C7FF', '#58AEFF', '#EA8BFF', '#FF61FF', '#FF40C5']
    ),
    link = dict(
      source = [0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 8, 8, 9, 11, 12, 12, 14, 14, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15],
      target = [2, 4, 5, 11, 12, 15, 9, 4, 12, 15, 2, 2, 4, 0, 3, 0, 2, 8, 14, 0, 4, 12, 14, 15],
      value = [6, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 6]
))

layout =  dict(
    title = "Sankey for log " + str(log_index),
    font = dict(
      size = 10
    )
)

fig=go.Figure(data=[data],layout=layout)
pio.write_image(fig, "./output/graphs/" + "Sankey for log " + str(log_index) + ".svg")
plotly.offline.iplot(fig, validate=False)

return {'sources': sankeyData['sources'], 'targets': sankeyData['targets'], 'values': sankeyData['values']}

allSankeyData = []

for i, log in enumerate(logs):
    allSankeyData.append(drawSankeyForAreaFlow(log["properties"]["area_flow"], i))
```

Answer (score 0):

Plotly doesn't support ANY circular references. At first I thought that was only meant for cases where nodes reference themselves but it appears it's meant also for cases like "A->B, B->A". For some weird reason my sankey graphs still got rendered but they were not saved.